# Celery task errors when getting facebook picture

Tags: django, celery, python-requests

I have the following celery task:

```
@task
def get_users_facebook_as_profile_icon(user_id, facebook_id):
    logger.info('Grabbing users facebook picture')
    url = "http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large" % facebook_id

    import requests
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Could not get facebook profile picture")
...
```

I have more after this, but I keep getting the following error:

```
"AssertionError('PID check failed. RNG must be re-initialized after fork(). Hint: Try Random.atfork()',)" 


Task was called with args: (3246, 17500596) kwargs: {}. 

The contents of the full traceback was: 

Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task 
R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 437, in __protected_call__ 
return self.run(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/home/ubuntu/mounzawebsite/mounza/celery_tasks/login_registration.py", line 42, in get_users_facebook_as_profile_icon 
hashname = user.generate_picture_name() 
File "/home/ubuntu/mounzawebsite/mounza/web/models.py", line 515, in generate_picture_name 
return generate_random_name(None) 
File "/home/ubuntu/mounzawebsite/mounza/web/models.py", line 40, in generate_random_name 
str(random.randint(1, 99982098098908237)) + 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 41, in get_random_bytes 
return _UserFriendlyRNG.get_random_bytes(n) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 213, in get_random_bytes 
return _get_singleton().read(n) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 163, in read 
return _UserFriendlyRNG.read(self, bytes) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 122, in read 
self._check_pid() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 138, in _check_pid 
raise AssertionError("PID check failed. RNG must be re-initialized after fork(). Hint: Try Random.atfork()") 
AssertionError: PID check failed. RNG must be re-initialized after fork(). Hint: Try Random.atfork()
```

I tried digging into this online, not able to find the root cause. but this is the only task where this error occurs. The only difference is that i'm downloading an image from Facebook, but I never see this issue anywhere else, including other tasks where I download images.

The URL works perfectly if I do it through a web browser, but it's only via this task it fails. Is there anything else that could contribute to this??

I have exhausted all attempts in fixing this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.amqp.celery.user/3664

always run teh below:

```
Crypto.Random.atfork()
```

When a new worker process is initialized. Done and done.